# Show dialog box on shift double click

Tags: wpf, dialog, command, mouseevent, routed-commands

My WPF application has a `TextBlock` control in it.  I want to display an "easter egg" when the user holds down the shift key and right double clicks on it.

I've added a `RoutedUiCommand` to a static class in my application where I've defined all of the commands.  I've added a command binding for my new command:

```
<UserControl.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding CanExecute="ShowDiagnostics_CanExecute" Command="cs:CarSystemCommands.ShowDiagnostics"  Executed="ShowDiagnostics_Executed" />
</UserControl.CommandBindings>
```

When I created the `RoutedUiCommand`, I specified a `MouseGesture` of `RightDoubleClick` with a `ModifierKey` of `Shift`.  So far so good.

How do I associate the command with the `TextBlock`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was to move the `CommandBinding` from the `UserControl.Resources` to the `TextBlock`:

```
<TextBlock ...>
    <TextBlock.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding CanExecute="ShowDiagnostics_CanExecute" Command="cs:CarSystemCommands.ShowDiagnostics"  Executed="ShowDiagnostics_Executed" />
    </TextBlock.CommandBindings>
</TextBlock>
```

Now, nothing happens until you hold down the shift key & right double click on the `TextBlock`.

I gave the other answers up votes because they'll work, too.

Answer (score 2):

You can use InputBindings and MouseBinding
Descipted here :http://thejoyofcode.com/Invoking_a_Command_on_a_Double_Click_or_other_Mouse_Gesture.aspx

Answer (score 1):

How about putting an [InputBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.inputbinding.aspx) on the text block that would call the command ?